# Azure VM two storages

Tags: azure

I'm using Azure VM (Ubuntu 16.04) as web server. For some reason at my resource group for VM there are two storages.
First - GRS Standart and second LRS Premium.
How to determine which storage is necessary for my web server and which I can safely delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the storage account holding the disks (OS and Data disks) by clicking on `Disks` option and then clicking on individual disks. You will see the URL of the page blob holding the disk and that should tell you about the storage account.

[image]

**However before deleting the other storage account, please check if it is not used for collecting diagnostics data for the VM**.

Making an assumption, I believe your `LRS Premium` account is holding the disks and the other one is for storing diagnostics data.